# Array goes out of index

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in the below code:

```
var Directions : Vector3[]; //*
function FindNext(){

if(Set.length == 0){
    Debug.Log("We're done.");
    return;
}  

var previous : Transform = Set[0]; 
var pScript : Cell = previous.GetComponent("Cell");

var next : Transform;
var nextScript : Cell;

var prevX : int = pScript.Position.x; 
var prevZ : int = pScript.Position.z; 

var randDirection : Vector3; 
var randSeed : int = Random.Range(0,4);

var nextX : int;
var nextZ : int; 
var counter : int; 

do{ 
    do{ 
        randDirection = Directions[randSeed];
        nextX = prevX+randDirection.x; 
        nextZ = prevZ+randDirection.z; 
        randSeed = (randSeed+1) % 4;
        counter++;
        if(counter > 4){ 
            Set.RemoveAt(0);
            previous.GetComponent.<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;  
            yield WaitForEndOfFrame();
            return;
        }  
    }while(nextX < 0 || nextZ < 0 || nextX + 1 >= GridSize.x || nextZ + 1 >= GridSize.z); 
    next = GridArr[nextX,nextZ];
    nextScript = next.GetComponent("Cell"); 
    //nextScript.IsOpened = false;
}while(nextScript.IsOpened); 


AddToSet(next); 

DrawDebugLines(10, previous, next);

ClearWalls(previous, next);

yield WaitForEndOfFrame(); 
}
```

For some reason there's a problem with the array index, and I don't really know what it is.

Below is the error that I get:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
Grid+$FindNext$5+$.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Grid.js:74)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine_Auto(IEnumerator)
Grid:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Grid.js:122)
```

I'm using UnityScript with Unity 5.

Comment: Problem solved with external variable inside scene. only set the Set Array in (0,1) (1,0) (1,1) (0,0)

Comment: Please consider answering your own question as it might help other people coming around ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution was simple, like this program are running on Unity, the array that was Out of Range it's a public array with transforms, so to fix the problem, the only thing that need to do it's set the array values:

```
(0,1)(1,0)(1,1)(1,0)
```

This values are because the array must contain the four possible direction in a maze.